# Trying to ID flight implications from June? Historical flight status?

Tags: delays, missed-flights

All the sources i checked arent offering historical flight status as far back as im looking (thats free).  Anyone able to help out and let me know what the issue/reason was for the delay?

TP1947 on June 28, 2018 from POT to LIS

Comment: At least one of the relevant sites has free trials for the subscription levels that give access to that data.

Comment: What do you mean by "ID flight implications"?

Comment: @jcaron - not true.  This is history from 9mo ago and neither FlightAware or FlightStats gives access that far back

Comment: @user93149 Flightradar24’s Gold subscription gives access to 365 days of history, and there’s a free 7-day trial.